# Core Plot - Graph show in fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, ios, graph, core-plot

I've created a basic graph with Core Plot. 
The graph succesfully showed in the center of the view, only I would like to show the Graph in fullscreen. Where can I change the frame size of the Graph?

I hope someone can help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The graph will always fill its hosting view. Since the hosting view is a subclass of `UIView`, you can position and size the same as you would any other view.

Comment: What about rotation?  The only way I've found to bring the core plot UIViewController to fullscreen is to presentViewControllerAnimated: completion: it...once the view is sized back down, it looks fine until you rotate the device again...it then resizes back to the "modal" dimensions inside the containing UIView.  How can this be avoided?  There are more details in a post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237390/core-plot-options-on-making-the-graph-full-screen-addsubview-after-presentin