# presentViewController is disabling all removeFromSuperview messages in a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

Here is a visual representation of the UISplitViewController:

[image]

I'm trying to present a UIViewController (myVC) that's a subview of a UIView inside the  DetailViewController of a UISplitViewController using this:

```
[appDelegate.splitViewController presentViewController:myVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

It presents, I dismiss it, the app rotates without a hitch, then when I try to reload the detail view by clicking on a cell in the rootViewController (a UINavigationController), all the [orangeUIView removeFromSuperview] messages are mysteriously disabled (there are more orange UIViews hidden here that are inside a mainScrollView).  The "INFO LABEL" in the topToolbar is updating, so I know the cell is sending data...

Why would this activity disable removeFromSuperview if presented using splitViewController?  I've presented myVC using the detailViewController...

```
[appDelegate.detailViewController presentViewController:myVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

which doesn't disable removeFromSuperview, but causes an assortment of other rotational crashes.

What's going on here?

Comment: "I'm presenting a UIViewController that's a subview of a smaller UIView inside the DetailViewController" -- this doesn't make sense. When a view controller is presented modally, it takes the whole screen, it can't be a subview (it's not a view, it's a view controller) of a smaller view inside a controller. You'll need to give more detail about your structure for us to help.

Comment: I've added myVC.view (Core Plot hostingView) to a UIView by addSubview that's 500x300 in the detail part of a split view...I want to present the myVC (UIViewController) instance fullscreen (since you can't present a UIView modally), which it does, then readd the myVC.view back into it's container, which it does.  The structure my be affected by how splitViewController handles modals, for instance, the settings for MainWindow_iPad.xib are set to present with "Current Context" with a transition style of "Flip Horizontal."  Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Good grief, I read that twice and still have no idea what it says. It would really help if you'd more clearly distinguish between ViewControllers and UIViews. You're using the very-different-thing terms kind of interchangeably: "...since you can't present a UIView modally" : well, no, you can't present a UIView at all. You can present a ViewController, and that you can present modally. Maybe you mean you want to add a UIView to your ViewController's root view and have fill the entire root view? Just not clear what you're doing or asking...

Comment: Forgive the confusion..I'm confused myself! See the added image for a visual representation.

Comment: @rdelmar, did the image help?

Comment: If you want to add myVC, as a view controller, then it needs to be added as a child view controller of whatever the controller in the right side of your split view is. But, like Bill Patterson, I'm confused by your imprecise use of terms. If you're "presenting" myVC, what's in that space before you present it? I also don't understand what you said in your first comment about presenting it full screen then adding it back into its container.

Comment: Ok...myVC is already added to the container ([container addSubview:myVC.view]) before I try to present it.  I want to see the Core Plot graph(myVC) full screen, so I present it modally (or whatever they call it these days after the deprecation of presentModalViewController in iOS 6).  Then I want to dismiss it and have the same instance intact where it was before, as you see in the image.  I'm sure you don't need a big red box that says, "Hi! I'm myVC presented modally!" that has the "X" button that dismisses it and puts it back into it's original blue UIView container.

Comment: @rdelmar, I read this about abusing view controllers: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/    As a self taught programmer like yourself, I think it's ok if I do [container addSubview:myVC.view], however container is a child view of detailViewControler...so am I essentially abusing view controllers by adding myVC to another VC?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be an abuse. First, it would be good to use the correct terms -- if you're talking about view hierarchies, the terms are subview and superview not child and parent, which are the terms to use for view controllers when one is embedded in another. As I said above, if you want to add a view controller's view as a subview of another controller's view, then that controller needs to be added as a child view controller. If you then want to present it modally, you would have to remove it from its parent, and then present it, and reverse that process when you want it back.

Comment: BTW, that blog you linked to is out of date, because Apple has now provided us with a way to do custom container controllers. You can read about them in the doc, "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller". This is what I'm talking about when I say to add something as a child view controller.

Comment: I was reading that when I saw you posted your comment!  Thanks for your patience with what appears to be a very beginner level problem from an advanced iOS developer..@Bill..although your Charlie Brownesque answer frustrated me even more, I see now why my terms are confusing..+1 for both of you for being a part of this complex yet simple problem.  I've never needed to properly create a custom container view controller until now, when I need to present myVC modally.  I will post an answer later for all those who are experiencing this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question was created as a result of a previous question, the answer to this problem was...try something else.  I was unable to fix this problem by presenting a view controller, most likely because I'm using a custom UISplitViewController with a hierarchy I'd rather not get into.

Here is the solution I came up with:

[Core Plot - Options on making the graph full screen - addSubview after presenting modal problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237390/core-plot-options-on-making-the-graph-full-screen-addsubview-after-presentin)